# how to verify insert & delete & update are done in single stored procedure of Ms Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write **stored procedure test case** for functionality checking.  I need to check that are there insert and/or delete operation done with update operation.  I tried with **BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)** for update but how can I know that whether table is inserted or deleted **for how many number of rows** with update operation **through result set**.

I am just using MS SQL Server 2005

Thanking You.

Comment: Are you using .Net or Java code to check the outcome of the stored procedure?

Comment: Well, you could use Triggers, but that could get messy and complicated to integrate into automated testing.  Other than that, you should probably copy the table before-hand and then compare it to the copy afterwards.  If you need to do this for many tables, then consider copying the whole database with backup to another database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:

> What I follow is inserting data into temp. table & actual table then
>   performing operation on one of them and ... checking the functionality
>   of the procedure.

If your final problem can be described as comparing actual and expected data within two tables, then you can try next approach - comparison using `except` clause:

```
create table [tb_source] (id int primary key identity(1,1), value varchar(50));
create table [tb_dest] (id int primary key, value varchar(50));


insert into [tb_source] (value) values ('a');
insert into [tb_source] (value) values ('b');
insert into [tb_source] (value) values ('c');

-- tables are equal
insert into [tb_dest] select * from [tb_source];

-- one row inserted
insert [tb_dest] (id, value) values (4, 'd');

-- one row deleted
delete from [tb_dest] where id = 1;

-- one row updated
update [tb_dest] set value = 'b_' where id = 2;

 -- answering the question "how many number of rows with update operation through result"
with [raw] as (
    (select *, 'deleted' [operation] from [tb_source]
    except 
    select *, 'deleted' from [tb_dest])
    union all
    (select *, 'inserted' from [tb_dest]
    except 
    select *, 'inserted' from [tb_source])),

[updates] as (
    select id
    from [raw]
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1),

[results] as (
    select * from [raw] where id not in (select id from [updates])
    union all
    select id, value, 'updated' from [raw] where id in (select id from [updates]))

select [operation], count(distinct id)
from [results]
group by [operation]
order by count(*) desc
```

Results:

```
operation   count
---------------------------------
updated         1
deleted         1
inserted        1
```

Comment: **@Andrey**    Dear, sir. Presented approach is more appealing to the solution of problem than approach that used by me, however as I am on leave and handover the issue to someone else I will reply for same as soon as possible after joining the workplace.

Comment: Dear sir, I discussed with my senior. Even he is agree with me. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

if shortly then:

- only delete       - delete
- only insert       - insert
- insert and delete - update

As an option you may try to use trigger to find out the type of the operation:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[MyTable]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare
        @i int = (select count(*) from (select top (1) * from inserted) as i),
        @d int = (select count(*) from (select top (1) * from deleted) as d),
        @type varchar(20);

    if @i = 1 and @d = 1 set @type = 'update'
        else if @i = 1 and @d = 0 set @type = 'insert'
            else if @i = 0 and @d = 1 set @type = 'delete'
                else set @type = 'empty'; 


    if @type = 'insert'
    begin
        -- YOUR CODE HERE
    end

    if @type = 'delete'
    begin
        -- YOUR CODE HERE
    end

    if @type = 'update'
    begin
        -- YOUR CODE HERE
    end

    if @type = 'empty'
    begin
        -- YOUR CODE HERE
    end


END
```

Comment: Dear sir, I need to check functionality through result check.

Comment: what can be better (more final) In this case than trigger :) You can insert operation info from trigger to the intermediate table (or through context_info()) and immediately analyse results within the test case procedure.

Comment: What I follow is inserting data into temp. table & actual table then performing operation on one of them and after that by means of sum(*) or BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) with use of appropriate join operation on both table checking the functionality of the procedure.

Comment: I'm using this tool http://tsqlt.org/ for unit testing and table comparations also

Comment: thanks for sharing, the company to which I am serving provide us there explicit framework define within stored procedure, I responsible to convey solutions according to them. So that I was asking for help with some internal logic rather than any additional tool.